# Why does Grails Command Object convert BigDecimal type to Integer?

Tags: grails, groovy

So, I have my Command Object and my class:

```
class AddOnBodyCommand implements Validateable {
  BigDecimal addOnPrice
}
class AddOnController {
  def addAddOnAction(AddOnBodyCommand body) {
    log.info("price: $body.addOnPrice")
  }
}
```

I have been working with CommandObject in my previous pages and I never had an error. But now, I have a form where I need to ask for a BigDecimal:

```
   <input type="number" step="0.01" id="newPriceAddOn" name="body.addOnPrice" value="0.55">
```

However, when I submit the form, the logger says the price is 55.

I could fix this using param.price instead of a CommandObject, but I'd like to use CommandObject because the code just looks cleaner and I can do validation in the CommandObject class. Any ideas?

To reproduce the issue: https://github.com/lRaulMN7/BigDecimalIssue and type 1123.45 in the input. The log.info will print 112345 instead of 1123.45

Comment: I think the name of the HTML `input` should be "addOnPrice" instead of "body.addOnPrice".

Comment: @PuneetBehl If I rename the input name, the filter won't read that value. So it won't pass validation, and the AddOnBodyCommand will be useless ^^'

Comment: I am not sure if I understand, which filter are you referring to here. Following is the sample Grails 4 application which demonstrates that a `BigDecimal` correctly binds to the object. https://github.com/puneetbehl/grailsBigDecimalBinding

Comment: @PuneetBehl When I talk about filter, I'm referring to my CommandObject AddOnBodyCommand. So when the name in the .gsp input is: 'body.addOnPrice', and I submit that form, and the controller AddOnController is called, the grails params variable has a "body" which contains the addOnPrice. And that "body" will have met all the constraints that I wanted to declare in the AddOnBodyCommand.

Comment: @PuneetBehl I saw your project but unfortunately you're not using Command Objects, so it is not useful for me :(. Also I'm using Grails 3.3.9

Comment: I am pretty sure it would still work with the command object. If you will look again, I have updated it to use the same and it's working.
Regarding Grails 3.3.9, I am pretty sure it would still behave the same. Please try creating a sample application similar to the one I shared and let me know if you see the problem.

Comment: @PuneetBehl I did a project to show you the issue. If you send a 123.45 , the index will print 12345. https://github.com/lRaulMN7/BigDecimalIssue